# Would you use self leveler on a 5/8 inch dip across 10 feet?

Tags: subfloor, self-leveling-concrete

I have a room where I want to lay down LVP but the middle of the room dips down to 5/8 inch across 10 feet. I'm planning on using self leveler here. Is this an acceptable fix?

Comment: Is it level the other way? The trick will self leveling compound is that it will flow, so if you've noted a dip east to west but not noticed (say) that the whole floor also slopes north to south, it may not do what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 3):

Fast answer is yes.

The long answer is, make sure the self leveling material is compatible with the substrate.
Also check the level of the floor in all directions. The worst thing you can do is place too much and still have the same problem, only in a different direction.

When I level floors, I use screws to set the depth of the mix that is going on the floor. Concrete screws for.... you guessed it, for concrete floors and wood screws for wood floors. The screws only need to go in about 3/4" to be stable enough to handle stepping on them while placing the material. No need to let them go through the floor too deep either, you may find a utility in the floor you do not want to know about.

I use a laser level to set mine, it makes it real easy, at least for me. You may only have a level, that will work well too. If you are using a level, a long straight edge will increase the usefulness of the level, by letting it span from high spot to high spot and checking to see if it is level between high spots. This will help you find where the dip begins around the perimeter. When it is determined, mark with a pencil or whatever, where the straightedge or level touch the floor at the high spots all around the depression. If it is level around the perimeter, all you need to do is set screws on a 2' grid pattern, so the head of the screws are level across the depression. Mark the floor where the grid line are beyond the depression so you can locate the screws easily when they are covered with cement.

Self leveling cement does not like to be less than 1/4" thick, and actually self level, anything less than that you will need to help it by troweling it up to the edges. DO NOT pour too much at one time, let the cement flow to the edge and gradually trowel it to the marked perimeter. If this is your first time doing this, it is real easy to place too much. You have about 10 minutes working time, and in about 20 minutes, it will start to gel and be reluctant to flow like it did at first.

After you think you have it down and done, look at the edges carefully, with a light, if need be shining it low across the floor. It will show any dips or high spots in your pour. You most like will see them at the edges, they can still be wiped down, spreading the perimeter out a little farther. Hopefully that will only need to be done once.  A second time will have the material at the gel stage, and you may need to wait to scrape, after it is ok to walk on after 3-6 ours, or whatever the directions say.

Comment: Man, this was like watching a YT video on how to do SLC, except written. Well done, sir!